# What is the different between first path attainer from a meditative commoner?

Tags: theravada

During meditation can path attainment be identified? How ? Is it gradually progressing  of the path in first path attainers?how this is differ from a meditative commoner?

Answer (score 1):

The common meditator [outsider] has wrong views, wrong conviction, wrong opinions in regards to the instruction generally presented by the Buddha to his disciples and is considered an outsider.

A person who doesn't hold wrong views, one who has faith in the parts of the dispensation generally presented by the Buddha is called a faith-follower. This person is guaranteed to attain the path-fruition of Sotapatti before passing away.

A person who has penetrated the meaning of that instruction & has come to an agreement through pondering those elements, is called a dhamma-follower but this not yet an awakening to the truth. This person is also guaranteed to attain the path-fruition of Sotapatti before passing away.

A person who having exerted himself, has both realized the ultimate meaning of the truth with his body & has seen with discernment, is said to have gone beyond conviction. This one has awakened to the truth, he knows & sees having realized the path of Sotapatti & lives having attained it's fruition.

Comment: Would  faith follower  and dhamma  follower attained fruit immediately after the path or after sometime?

Answer (score 0):

> During meditation can path attainment be identified? How ?

Yes. The noble right view is what the ordinary have been before, so they don't find any view and paths like this before by the past-lives-recollection, when the practitioner meditated the 4th Jhana at mastery level and look back his past lives with analysis the arising and vanishing trillion times per second of Nama and Rupa, they will realize "this right view never happen before even in the lives which I was a Jhana-Mastery-Attainner".

> Is it gradually progressing of the path in first path attainers?how this is differ from a meditative commoner?

No any ordinary has the right view before in the past lives, never.

So, when the ordinary look back on the past lives, nothing like the first path appeared.

**An enlightening moment never happens in an ordinary person's past lives.**

However, the difference from the common concentration meditation attainment is insight meditation, the viewing of trillion times per second mind arising and vanishing. This happened before in past lives but never access an enlightenment moment for an ordinary.

Comment: How to identify the access an enlightenment  ,is it mind shut down?

Comment: No, mind is shut down form 5 strings on Jhana-Attainment as well. So, the first core is 
 the right view, of the dependent origination,  which never happens in any past lives before.

Comment: So if you see through  the meditation ignorance  cause mind fabrications will it leads to enlightenment?

Comment: 1. According to many Suttas, Sotapanna to Anagami still have an ignorance and mind fabrications, except wrong view. 2. Stop thinking is good because the practitioner can stop knowing 5 strings to focus on 8 Jhana Mastery for 8 Vijja. They all support each others step by step. However, stop thinking is not 
only  enlightenment moment. The ordinary's jhana also stop thinking too.

Comment: Reduction of obsessive thoughts as noticed when they were appearin, samadhi  leads to reduce clinging will that put on to the right view?